# MAVEN POM XML START_TAG END_TAG

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

The following code is from MAVEN POM.XML but it is not working:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0>
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ActiveMQ</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <properties>
         <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    </project>
```

In this code I get following error in the first line:

> TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG
> (position:START_TAG seen ... \n ...@15:22) :2

What is wrong with it?

Comment: In line 4 a closing " is missing.

Comment: You miss double quotes afer `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

`"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0`

into

`"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0"`

You missed the closing double quote.

Comment: i added a double quote but it didn' help, the same error occurs once again

Comment: Please, post your full POM.XML file.